# Getting application model from HttpContext

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Thanks to the superior design of ASP.NET Core, it's an improved challenge to find things.

I want to get at the `ApplicationModel` in order to walk the controller and action descriptors.

I take it there's no static anywhere, so I need to get it from an `HttpContext`. I can get to a feature and a service provider.

So I can request services and features. The list of built-in services I found in the docs doesn't list anything useful regarding getting at the application model.

There's a [long article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/application-model) in the documentation describing in epic length how to modify it, but no word is lost on how to get at it as far as I can tell.

Comment: Did you try injecting `IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider` and then using that to enumerate?

Comment: @stephen.vakil Injection fails. The error message suggests that it was merely trying to default-construct the interface, which of course isn't possible.

Comment: Please post your `Startup` then.  Using the default core mvc templates you should be able to inject it into any controller.

Comment: @stephen.vakil My mistake, it does work: Before, I had the provide parameter on the action, not the ctor. Apparently I can also request the provider from the `RequestServices`, so that covers it then. Many thanks.

Comment: If you want to inject a service into an action, you have to use `[FromServices]IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider provider`

Comment: Jeez, I wish at least one of you had posted a brief answer with some sample code, I'm trying to do exactly this myself and haven't a clue where to start even with the suggestions above.